# Contar registro de dois campos de datas agrupando por ano

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso obter a soma de registros de dois campos de uma mesma tabela porém agrupando o ano para montar um gráfico AreaChart

--

### -- Estrutura da tabela `cadastros`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastros` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`inicio_contrato` date NOT NULL,
`fim_contrato` date NOT NULL,
`datacad` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`ativo` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

--

### -- Extraindo dados da tabela `cadastros`

```
INSERT INTO `cadastros` (`ID`, `inicio_contrato`, `fim_contrato`, `datacad`, `ativo`) 
VALUES
(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', '2015-01-15 05:16:53', '0'),
(2, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', '2015-09-15 07:18:08', '0'),
(3, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', '2015-09-15 07:54:07', '0'),
(4, '2015-01-01', '0000-00-00', '2015-09-15 08:31:45', '1'),
(5, '2016-01-01', '0000-00-00', '2016-09-15 04:17:12', '1'),
(6, '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31', '2016-09-15 06:18:32', '0'),
(7, '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31', '2016-09-15 06:18:08', '0'),
(8, '2017-01-01', '2017-03-31', '2017-09-15 08:12:43', '0'),
(9, '2017-01-26', '0000-00-00', '2017-01-26 07:38:36', '1'),
(10, '2017-03-31', '0000-00-00', '2017-03-31 08:44:13', '1');
```

Preciso que me imprima o resultado abaixo:

```
['ANO', 'INICIO', 'FIM'],
['2015', '4', '3'],
['2016', '3', '2'],
['2017', '3', '1']
```

Em minha tentativa consegui fazer contar um campo mas ainda não conseguir contar os dois na mesma query:

```
SELECT YEAR(inicio_contrato) AS anos,
COUNT(YEAR(inicio_contrato)) AS total
FROM cadastros 
GROUP BY anos 
ORDER BY anos DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Desta forma eu consigo agrupar por ANO e contar o INICIO

Comment: Olá, adiciona por favor os registros de exemplo que você tem na tabela. Ideal que não sejam muitos, e sim alguns poucos o suficiente para caracterizar o problema/situação.

Comment: Quais campos você quer somar especificamente ?

Comment: Precisa CONTAR quantos registros tiveram inicio em cada ano utilizando a coluna `inicio_contrato` e CONTAR quantos tiveram fim utilizando a coluna `fim_contrato` quando a mesma houver valor (data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você está agrupando por colunas diferentes, precisa tratar as *queries* separadamente.

Podemos partir da *query* simples, com base na sua:

```sql
    SELECT
      YEAR( inicio_contrato ) AS ano,
      COUNT( * ) AS contagem
    FROM
      cadastros
    GROUP BY
      YEAR( inicio_contrato )
    ORDER BY
      inicio_contrato
```

E, em seguida, aplicar a mesma lógica para o fim, usando um JOIN para mostrar os dois retornos relacionados:

```sql
SELECT
   inicio.ano,
   inicio.contagem,
   fim.contagem
FROM (
      --- aqui vai a query inicial ---
      SELECT
         YEAR( inicio_contrato ) AS ano,
         COUNT( * ) AS contagem
      FROM
         cadastros
      GROUP BY
         YEAR( inicio_contrato )
      ORDER BY
         inicio_contrato

   ) inicio JOIN (
      --- mesma lógica, para o fim ----
      SELECT
         YEAR( fim_contrato ) AS ano,
         COUNT( * ) AS contagem
      FROM
         cadastros
      GROUP BY
         YEAR( fim_contrato )
      ORDER BY
         fim_contrato

   ) fim ON inicio.ano = fim.ano
ORDER BY
   inicio.ano;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb6825/1)**.